# MAGENTO : Add downloadable with Physical product or simple product

Tags: magento, download, mp3, product

I can't believe I can't find an answer to this.

We want to offer cds that INCLUDE both the digital and physical copies of a cd in one purchase.( so I'm not looking for one of the several 'add a product manual as a download' extensions, unless said extension)

<strike>Creating a bundle don't work because you can't add downloadable products to bundles.</strike>

I can modify /app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/etc/config.xml Around line 106 to add < downloadable/ > as an option for bundles. But I feel this is still a workaround.

This seems like something that should be included in the core.

Isn't the only difference between a downloadable product and a simple product the download? ( and no shipping) Shouldn't it be easy to add that download field to a simple or configurable product?

This is the closest I can find, but requires way too much customization [INCHOO - How to create a new product type in Magento](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-create-a-new-product-type-in-magento/)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bundle product in magento

Comment: I had to modify app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/etc/config.xml to be able to do that, and even that seems like a hack/hassle. I don't always want the mp3 as a sku in the system. I would just like a physical product that includes a download.  It quickly becomes cumbersome to need to make bundles for every music product we offer. But thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue is when you have a sample file attached to the download, cant have a sample for a file.